# Reusing javascript in java

Tags: javascript, java, cucumber, nashorn, avatarjs

I've got a challenge in my current organization on re-using the capabilities written on javascript in our java code. Just to give a background:

We have two different automation frameworks:

1. Java using maven - Uses Cucumber jvm and selenium with page object model - This is mostly maintained by testers
2. Javascript framework - User cucumber js and selenium web driver - This is maintained by UI developers

The challenge here is we wanted to converge both the frameworks and re-use the capabilities between both. My idea is re-using the page objects at least elements and some helper methods between both the frameworks.

Say for an example:

1. I have page elements captured in `Login.js` file and contains few helper methods like generating the random email address.
2. I should be able to import the `Login.js` file in my Java class and also should be able to use the page elements and helper method written in javascript.

What I found was cucumber rhino to use the capabilities from java to javascript. Whereas the other way round is not possible.

I can use java 8's scripting engine `Nashorn` to load the js modules in java, but the same cannot be used if my JS modules are written using `Node`. And yeah cucumber.js is node module :(

I came across [Avatar js](https://avatar-js.java.net) which can be used to load the node modules in the jvm. But again the Avatar does not have the support for `Cucumber`. I tried and failed.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - forget about Avatar, it's on a very old version and additionally [the project is dead](http://www.n-k.de/2015/02/current-status-of-oracles-project-avatar.html)!

Using node modules in Nashorn is possible, as long as they are not base on native api. If you need the `require()` function, you can use [jvm-npm](https://github.com/nodyn/jvm-npm). But be sure to resolve all the (transitive) dependencies before on your own or running `npm install` or similar maven/gradle plugins to resolve npm dependencies.

When loading NPM modules in Nashorn, you should load something like a [nashorn-polyfill.js](https://gist.github.com/dasniko/6494bf2c3e0eb8dc2e8a) before, because there are some variables, which aren't available in Nashorn, so you have to provide them on your own (maybe, you need some more/additional variables, not yet in my polyfill file available).

I don't know cucumber.js, so I can't provide you tipps how to get cucumber running in Nashorn. But I run `React.JS` for example in my java server-side code to pre-render the DOM on the server and send it to the client. And React.JS is also a non-trivial NPM lib, but it works like a charm!

Comment: Could you please share some example on how you did with the react js? I tried your approach and works fine. But unable to reuse any values from my javascript. I'll add the GIST soon on what I tried.

Comment: Here you go: https://gist.github.com/email2vimalraj/04ed8be969c540770906. I would like to use the value of `myVar` in my java code.